# Insets with different sided faces to original

Tags: mesh, faces

Say you have a plane, or one face of a mesh selected. You press I to inset. The inset shape will be the same as the face/plane you are insetting. Can the inset be a different shape, to the face/plane? For instance, a circular inset in a square.

I know you can achieve similar results with a boolean modifier, or even the bridge edge loops function. However, if this sort of inset function exists, it would make things faster and more convenient. If not...well, not a big deal, I suppose.